# strange behaviour same code but in different chapters

Tags: listings

I've just come accross a problem I'm unable to solve.

I use this code in chapter 2 and it all works fine :

```
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting}
<?php
$template = 'blue.php';
    if ( is_set( $_COOKIE['TEMPLATE'] ) )
    $template = $_COOKIE['TEMPLATE'];
include("/home/users/phpguru/templates/". $template );
?>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{ttfamily}
```

Then I actually use the same code in chapter 4, but surprisingly I get a boxed (or framed)
result:

```
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting}
// connect to the database
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
// dynamically build the sql statement with the input
$query = "SELECT userid FROM CMSUsers WHERE user = '$_GET["user"]' " .
"AND password = '$_GET["password"]'";
// execute the query against the database
$result = mysql_query($query);
// check to see how many rows were returned from the database
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
// if a row is returned then the credentials must be valid, so
// forward the user to the admin pages
if ($rowcount != 0){ header("Location: admin.php");}
// if a row is not returned then the credentials must be invalid
else { die('Incorrect username or password, please try again.')}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{ttfamily}
```

I must say that in chapter 3 (so different location but before the strange behaviour occured in chapter 4, so to speak) 
I use this code in order to get a framed code snippet:

```
\lstset{framexleftmargin=0mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black},basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{lstlisting}
root@bt:~# echo -en "GET/HTTP/1.0\n\n\n"|nc www.we****t***.com 80\
>|grep Server
Server: Apache/2.2.15
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Identificazione server}
\end{figure}
```

What should I do? I tried to delete all files not having .tex extension (aux,toc,bak..etc), but to no avail.

Comment: You've changed the `listings` settings in Chapter 3, and assuming the obvious logical order, these settings will apply in Chapter 4 (_etc._). You'll need to either localise the settings or reset them at the start of Chapter 4.

Comment: What should I do exactly in chapter 3?...I believe the problem is here : \lstset{framexleftmargin=0mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black},basicstyle=\ttfamily\small} Am I right? But I don't know what to do..

Comment: A full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be useful here. What I'm really not clear on is whether the change in Chapter 3 applies to several items or just one or two: if it's the latter, the best approach will be to localise the change.

Comment: As I said the change is in chapter 3 and it took place twice..

Comment: When you use `\lstset` it applies those changes to *all*  `lstlisting` environments that follow, so you're seeing the expected behaviour. To apply settings to a single `lstlisting`, use the optional argument to the environment: `\begin{lstlisting}[frame=shadowbox, <any other settings you want>]`

Comment: Could you please try to rewrite your heading to be more informative? It would also be greatly appreciated if you looked back into some of your older questions and accepted an answer if you feel there is one which solves your problem.

Answer (score 7):

As @Torbjørn says the `\lstset` command has a global scope, so it affects every listing after it. That's why your listing in Chapter 4 gets framed. If you only want one listing to be framed, use the optional argument to the environment:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[framexleftmargin=0mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black}, basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]
```

You should also use `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` already in Chapter 3 instead of `\begin{ttfamily}`.

Comment: an alternative might be just to move the `\lstset` code inside the `figure` environment; unless the listings package defines `\lstset` as global, the alteration should go away at the end of the `figure`.